# Get file name and file extension in linux distribution using powershell

Tags: linux, powershell

I used the following script on CentOS to get a file extension and file name without extension and full file name and it worked well on Windows, but when I use it on ubuntu it did not work and it showed me plenty of errors:

> Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] does not contain a 
>     method named 'LastIndexOf'.
>
> Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] does not contain a method named 'Substring'.

Below you can find the code that I wrote

```
$files = get-childitem /etc/ssl/certs
foreach ($file in $Files)
{ 
# Nom du fichier avec extension
$pos_last_anti_slash = $file.LastIndexOf("\")
$fullname = $files.Substring($pos_last_anti_slash+1)
# Extension du fichier
$pos_last_point = $file.LastIndexOf(".")
$extension = $file.Substring($pos_last_point+1)
Write-Host $extension

# Nom du fichier sans extension
$filename = $file.Substring($pos_last_anti_slash+1)
$pos_last_points = $filename.LastIndexOf(".")
$filename = $filename.Substring(0,  $pos_last_points)
Write-Host $filename
if($filextension == "p7b")
{
openssl x509 -inform p7b -in /etc/ssl/certs/$fullname -out 
/etc/ssl/certs/$filename.pem
$var = ((& openssl x509 -in $file -dates -noout) -match 'notAfter')

}
}
```

Comment: Use the PowerShell cmdlet `Split-Path -Leaf`, or the properties BaseName,Name,Extension of `$file` no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This shouldn't work on windows either. (Oh and linux doesn't split paths with a backslash, it uses the slash as you used it on the first line.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Get-Member` cmdlet to see what fields the file object has. I think that FullName, BaseName, Extension, and Name may be of interest.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path '/etc/ssl/certs' | Get-Member
```

I have not tested this, but it might be close to what you are seeking. I did replace `==` with `-eq`.

```
$certsdir = '/etc/ssl/certs'
$files = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $certsdir
foreach ($file in $files) { 
    # Nom du fichier avec extension
    $fullname = $_.Name

    # Extension du fichier
    $extension = $_.Extension
    Write-Host $extension

    # Nom du fichier sans extension
    $filename = $_.BaseName
    Write-Host $filename

    if ($filextension -eq ".p7b") {
        openssl x509 -inform p7b -in $_.FullName -out $(Join-Path -Path $certsdir -ChildPath "$filename.pem")
        $var = ((& openssl x509 -in $file -dates -noout) -match 'notAfter')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I tried your script with some modifications and it worked  till the command `$var = ((& openssl x509 -in "/etc/ssl/certs/$filename.pem" -dates -noout) -match 'notAfter)` that showed me the following error `bat input format for certificate  & unable to load certificate`